# How to check NSManagedObjectContext unsaved?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

How to check that NSManagedObjectContext unsaved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[context hasChanges]
```

returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the context has uncommitted changes.

Comment: Was very simple. Thank you!